# jQuery Looping Animation with Counter

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate, counter

I'm trying to create a simple colour change animation on a div with a counter inside that counts how many times the animation has looped. I thought this would be simple but it's actually causing me headaches.

```
function AttachGo() {
    $('a#GoButton').click(function() {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $('div#Timer').animate({
                backgroundColor: "#FF0000"
            }, 1000, 'linear',
                $('div#Timer').css("backgroundColor", "#22FF22"),
                $('p#Count').text("Completed: " + i)
            );
        }
    });
}
```

I've got a example I'm playing with [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PottyMonster/pG6us/).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: in your sample, where are you calling `AttachGo` ?

Comment: AttachGo is called onLoad.

I should have added that the main problem I'm having is getting the text to change with the count. The looping did work when I had a function embedded within the complete function but this seems ill-advised when part of a loop.

Comment: the for loop will execute faster than the animate and by the time animate is called i value is already 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put cycle calling as callback for animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/pG6us/2/

Comment: simply call function itself as animation callback

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the `step` function of `animate`. look here: blog.gabrieleromanato.com/2011/03/jquery-animation-steps/